# Error trying reversing words in a string using python

Tags: python, string

```
def spin_words(sentence):
    for word in sentence.split():
        if len(word)>=5:
            words = word[::-1]
    new_sentence = sentence.replace(word,words) 
    return new_sentence
spin_words('Hey fellow warriors')


#output is 'Hey fellow sroirraw'
```

i'm trying to reverse some words in a string that are greater than five characters but i only get one word reversed.

Comment: `words` gets overritten in the loop, only the last word >=5 will be reversed. Also if no word is long enough you will have an error since `words` will never be set.

Answer (score 4):

It is easier to store the sentence as an array and change each element independently than modifying the entire sentence on each iteration.

```
def spin_words(sentence: str):
    words = sentence.split()
    for idx, word in enumerate(words):
        if len(word) >= 5:
            words[idx] = word[::-1]
    return ' '.join(words)

rev = spin_words('Hey fellow warriors')
print(rev)  # Hey wollef sroirraw
```

**Note:** This solution does *not* preserve consecutive spaces or newlines.

Comment: This is better than my adapted approach and would also properly handle the situation where some words are part of other words.

Answer (score 1):

You should e.g. move the reversal into the loop itself:

```
def spin_words(sentence):
    for word in sentence.split():
        if len(word)>=5:
            words = word[::-1]
            sentence = sentence.replace(word, words) 
    return sentence

spin_words('Hey fellow warriors')
```

You should also be wary of words being parts of other words, e.g. in `tester anothertester`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your code:

```
def spin_word(this_word):
    rotated_list = list(this_word.lower())[::-1]
    rotated_word = ''.join(rotated_list)
    return rotated_word

def spin_frase(frase):
    rotated_frase = []
    for word in frase.split():
        if len(word) >= 5:
            rotated_frase.append(spin_word(word))
        else:
            rotated_frase.append(word)
    print(' '.join(rotated_frase))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spin_frase('Hey fellow warriors')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).